# Unable to install TFS2018 with Sql Server 2016 SP1

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am setting up my development environment for TFS2018 with SQL Server 2016 , i have already installed the following :-

1. sql server 2016 sp1. [ServerDB]
   ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2017 ===>>> Exting Instance for TFS2017
   ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2018 ===>>> New Instanct for TFS2018
   ServerDB\Administrator for install DB
2. TFS2018 [ServerApp]
   ServerApp\Administrator for install TFS (connect to ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2018)

But during my TFS2018 installation i am getting the following errors:-

> TF255507: The security identifier (SID) for the following SQL Server login conflicts with a specified domain or workgroup account: ServerDB\Administrator. The domain or workgroup account is: SIAM-TFD-03\Administrator.  The server selected to host the databases for Team Foundation Server is: SIAM-DBS-06\MSSQLTFS2018.
>   You can resolve this issue by renaming the conflicting login. To do so, open a command prompt on the computer that is running SQL Server and execute the following command:
>   sqlcmd -E -S "ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2018" -Q "ALTER LOGIN [ServerDB\Administrator] WITH NAME = [ServerApp\Administrator]"

Result after exceute cmd above:

> Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Server ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2018, Line 1
>   Windows NT user or group 'ServerApp\Administrator' not found. Check the name again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this way and it work.

On  [ServerDB]
 - I create user domain\tfsuser on MSSQL

On  [ServerApp]
 - I login with user domain\tfsuser and Reinstall TFS with user domain\tfsuser

Installation completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could login SSMS to check whether the account `ServerApp\Administrator` has been added to instance `ServerDB\MSSQLTFS2018`. Add it manually if it is not there:

[image]

Also, you could check the solutions in this blog to see whether it helps you:

https://stepbistep.net/2013/03/04/tf255507-the-security-identifier-sid-for-the-following-sql-server-login-conflicts-with-a-specified-domain-or-workgroup-account/

Comment: thank you and i apologized after I posted I was admitted in a hospital
I tried with your reply but not work for me.